# Average run time differences between random search in a sorted list versus non-random search in an unsorted list.

Tags: list, search, runtime, average

As stated by the title, what, if there is any, is the average run time difference between searching for a random element in a sorted list versus searching for a non-random element in an unsorted list.

To further explain the problem, imagine two scenarios.

**Scenario A**
Given a list of sorted integers 1 - 500,000, find an integer x. x is a randomly generated number

**Scenario B**
Given a randomly generated, unsorted list of integers ranging from 1 - 500,000, find an integer x. x could be some arbitrary number.

Comment: Hi, pls add in which language you want to do.. please ask questions related to code not logic.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm currently thinking about this in C++, but I'm not really concerned with what the code would look like. I just want to know if there's any difference in run time between the two scenarios when performed on a large scale.